# Copying value to actual parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a pckage plch_pkg as follows

```
create type plch_number_nt is table of number;
create or replace package plch_pkg
authid definer
is
     g_numbers plch_numbers_nt:=plch_numbers_nt(1);
     procedure empty_the_nt_fail(numbers_io IN OUT plch_numbers_nt);
     procedure empty_the_nt(numbers_io IN OUT plch_numbers_nt);
end plch_pkg;
create or replace package body plch_pkg
is
     procedure empty_the_nt_fail(numbers_io in out plch_numbers_nt)
     is
     begin
         dbms_output.put_line('empty_the_nt_fail');
         numbers_io.delete;
         raise program_error;
     end empty_the_nt_fail;
     procedure empty_the_nt(numbers_io in out plch_numbers_nt)
     is
     begin
         dbms_output.put_line('empty_the_nt');
         numbers_io.delete;
     end empty_the_nt;
end plch_pkg;
```

Later I created this procedure.

```
   create or replace procedure plch_proc
   authid definer
   is
        l_numbers plch_numbers_nt := plch_numbers_nt(1);
        procedure show_numbers
        is
        begin
            dbms_output.put_line('count='||l_numbers.count);
        end;
        begin

             plch_pkg.empty_the_nt_fail(l_numbers);
             show_numbers;
        exception
             when others then
                  show_numbers;

  end plch_proc;
```

Now when i call this procedure as follows

```
declare
begin
    plch_proc;
end;
```

I get the output as count=0.
   This is my understanding. My procedure plch_proc the empty_the_nt_fail        procedure in the plch_pkg.After deleting all the elements from numbers_io nested table,it raises an error.
The oracle documentation says that "Only when the procedure has finished without exception is the result value copied back to the formal parameter".
This copying of numbers_io to my actual parameter l_numbers should not happen as the error occured. But when I called the procedure plch_proc,it printed the count as 0,which means that formal parameter value was copied to actual parameter. Could somebody please explain

I found the explaination for copying actual parameters and formal parameters     here
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#895

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/08_subs.htm#i23202

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_nocopy_data_structures.htm

Comment: Please edit your question and include a link to the documentation you quoted. Thanks.

Comment: I've created an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f699/2 running on Oracle 11.2 (slightly modified to bypass SQLFiddle restrictions) - and it's result is `count=0`. The same case tested on Oracle 12c returns `count=1`.  In my opinion it appears to be a bug in Oracle 11.2,